# How to use dynamoDB in offline mode in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, amazon-dynamodb, offline

I am using dynamoDB in my xamarin application as an online database .

It works well in the online mode but it craches in the offline mode ,

but I need it to work when I am in offline mode then to synchronize the

changes in the online mode ( when the internet is back ) .

Is this possible using dynamoDB ?

Thank you .

Here is some code :

```
        credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials("", // Identity pool ID
                  // Region
                 );

        client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
        context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
        List<ScanCondition> conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
        var search = context.ScanAsync<Book>(conditions);
        books = new ObservableCollection<Book>( search.GetNextSetAsync().Result);
        return search.GetNextSetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that if you use AppSync to connect to your database you will have offline data synchronization:
https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/product-details/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: Is it available on Xamarin please ?

Comment: There should be a c# sdk to connect to AppSync. You should know that you develop AppSync with all its endpoints and mapping templates within AWS itself. Then you connect to it with you frontend code.